# Parse HTML fragment with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, dynamic-html

I have a part of a screen that is retrieved dynamically through AJAX, and replaces an existing part (think about a paginated grid, that when you click on "next" you get a new HTML table than replaces the current). That fragment may content AngularJS bindings, like some directives that needs to be attached or minor data bindings.

Is there a way to make AngularJS parse that new fragment without reparse the whole document?

Comment: That's what [$compile](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.7/docs/api/ng/service/$compile) is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)
for example you have

```
var htmlText = "<div>{{name}} <select>...</select></div>";
```

in your directive you can do like this

```
$scope.compiled= $compile(htmlText)($scope);
```

To parse a replaced section of the document would be:

```
var el = angular.element(document.getElementById('#container'));
el.html(ajaxHtml);
$compile(el.contents())(scope);
```